# Shopping Cart To Json

Tags: jquery, json

i need to generate a json data on a button click but i am unable to get the json
my shopping cart demo link
http://jsfiddle.net/bkw5p/48/

Comment: Which button, and what does the JSON represent?  How is it created?  How is it going to be used by other parts of your program?  Is it safe to put all of the information in it that you want to?  And do you download it from the server on click, or do you build it?  Do you upload it on click, or do you use it to update other parts of your application, like the total price view?

Comment: on a button click means which button? the  link has remove button only

Comment: sorry i need to get the json data while clicking on submit order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end of HTML, between `<p class="total">` and `<h2>`:

```
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Make an order" />
```

In JS inside the `$(function() { ... })`:

```
$('#submit').bind('click',function(){
    if (!$('table#cartcontent1 tr').length) {
        alert('You have no Items in Your Cart');
    } else {

        var result = new Array();
        var name, qty, price;
        $('table#cartcontent1 tr').each(function(){
            name = $(this).find('td[data-bind="text:name"]').text();
            qty = $(this).find('input[data-bind="value:qty"]').val();
            price = $(this).find('td[data-bind="text:price"]').text();
            result.push( {'name' : name, 'qty' : qty, 'price' : price } );
        })

        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url: 'ordering.php',
            data: {data: result},
            success: function(msg){
                // do something when success
            }
        });
    }
    return false;
})
```

In PHP it will be like:

```
$data = $_POST['data'];
foreach ($data as $val) {
    echo $val['name']; // Feeling
    echo $val['price']; // 25
    echo $val['qty']; // 3
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer it worked grate but i am unable to alert it my alert(result);  i get the alert as [object],[object]

Comment: Yes, this is an array of objects. Use `console.log(result)` and see the result in console